# Leaflet Getlatlngs to number

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to convert a layer.GetLatLngs to an array with only numbers,

`[[17.68397, 1.98629],[17.6777, 1.96555],[17.66679, 1.9648],[17.6611, 1.99233]]`

Problem is that the output is something along

`LatLng(17.50438, 1.04772),LatLng(17.48686, 1.05775)`

What's the best way to do a number only conversion to an array?

//Snippet of the code

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;
if (type === 'polygon') {
    layer.on('click', function() {
        window.alert(polys);    
    });
}

drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
polys = layer.getLatLngs();
});
```

Comment: like you need the output to be [[17.68397, 1.98629],[17.6777, 1.96555],[17.66679, 1.9648],[17.6611, 1.99233]] 
 input is LatLng(17.50438, 1.04772),LatLng(17.48686, 1.05775)

Comment: They are two examples, but yes, in general I need the coordinates in an array without Latlng.

Comment: so the  "LatLng(17.50438, 1.04772),LatLng(17.48686, 1.05775)"  is a string isn't

Comment: Actually, it counts as an array `getLatLngs() LatLng[] 
Returns an array of the points in the path, or nested arrays of points in case of multi-polyline.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`getLatlngs`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#polyline-getlatlngs) return an array of [`LatLng`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#latlng) objects. To get a list of coordinate pairs, you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each object. For example,

```
layer.getLatLngs().map(function(point) {
    return [point.lat, point.lng];
});
```

And a demo

```js
var latlngs = [
    [45.51, -122.68],
    [37.77, -122.43],
    [34.04, -118.2]
];
var layer = L.polyline(latlngs);
var resp = layer.getLatLngs().map(function(point) {
    return [point.lat, point.lng];
});

console.log(resp)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
```

or if your intent is rather to get a representation of your layer, use [`toGeoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#polyline-togeojson) instead to get the underlying geometry:

```
layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates
```

Here's another demo with a polygon

```js
var latlngs = [[37, -109.05],[41, -109.03],[41, -102.05],[37, -102.04]];
var layer = L.polygon(latlngs);
console.log(layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: This returns an array of two undefined values for me, most likely because I'm already doing a polygon on the layer. Here's a snippet of the code I'm running `map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    if (type === 'polygon') {
        layer.on('click', function() {
            window.alert(polys);    
        });
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
 polys = layer.getLatLngs();`     formatting this in the comments isn't that easy

Comment: Yes, your solution worked fine as well and is most likely a bit more clean

Answer (score 0):

i hope the below code works. Please check and let me know. happy Coding :)

```js
let string = "LatLng(17.50438, 1.04772),LatLng(17.48686, 1.05775)",
    splittedArray = string.split("LatLng"),
    outputArray = [];
 
splittedArray.forEach(o => {
  if(o){
   let extractedLTLNG =  o.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(",");
   let tempArray = [extractedLTLNG[0], extractedLTLNG[1]];
     outputArray.push(tempArray);
  }else{
   return;
  }
})

console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! With a little bit of tinkering your code worked perfectly